# puppet resource declaration error

Tags: linux, centos, puppet

I have the following error when I run puppet on the a machine which has been assigned this class.

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: 
Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Duplicate declaration: Class[<<dir_for_node_type>>::<brand_dir>::Awscli] is already declared; 
cannot redeclare at /etc/puppet/environments/prod/modules/<dire_for_node_type>/manifests/<brand_dir>/awscli.pp:3 at /etc/puppet/environments/prod/modules/<dir_for_node_type>/manifests/<brand_dir>/awscli.pp:3:2 on node <node_name>
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

I have the following in the parameter file which sits in a seperate repository:

```
cat /<rep_name>/modules/<dir_for_node_type>/manifests/<brand_dir>/awscli.pp
class <dir_for_node_type>::<brand_dir>::awscli
{
        class { 'awscli':
        }  ->
        awscli::profile { 'default':
          aws_access_key_id     => '<key_id>',
          aws_secret_access_key => '<sec_key_id>'
        }
}
```

I have tried to replicate this error on my local and I simply put in the class twice in the site.pp, I got a very similar error, however the output was slightly different as it gave exactly where the two declarations are, where as the error above doesn't give the first declaration, here is the error i get on my local:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: 
Duplicate declaration: Class[Awscli] is already declared in file /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp:8; 
cannot redeclare at /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp:24 on node <node_name>
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Comment: That error statement normally means that you declared it twice in that manifest, which means you need to provide more information about what that manifest is doing.

Comment: That  above file (awscli.pp) is the entire manifest, Unless you mean the files under the manifest folder from the original module which I downloaded from https://forge.puppet.com/jdowning/awscli. I have not modified that in any way, I simply created a parameter file awscli.pp shown above.